# Set Size of SWT Composite inside a TabFolder

Tags: swt

How can I set the Width and Height of a Composite in a tab folder?

PS: `setSize` and `setBounds` doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't said when, where and how you are setting the composite size, therefore, I am assuming that you are setting the size on an event, and well, `setSize` works for me.

I am on Win7, eclipse 4.2 and JDK 1.6_b30. See the sample code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;


public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        TabFolder folder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.TOP);
        folder.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        folder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));


        TabItem item = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("Tab 1");

        final Composite composite = new Composite(folder, SWT.BORDER);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        text.setText("Tab 1");
        Button b = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
        b.setText("Press");
        b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                composite.setSize(23, 43);
            }
        });

        item.setControl(composite);

        shell.setSize(300, 200);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

***`Before Pressing the Button`***

[image]

***`After Pressing the Button`***

[image]

Though there is catch! As soon as you resize your application, the composite comes back to its **original size** !!

---

Also there **could be a problem** if you don't use any event for setting size (may be some bug or feature in SWT tab-folder). A very non-intrusive **`hack`** (which does not need any user interaction) is to use `PaintListener`. See the below code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;


public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        final TabFolder folder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.TOP);
        folder.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        folder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));


        TabItem item = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("Tab 1");

        final Composite composite = new Composite(folder, SWT.BORDER);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        text.setText("Tab 1");


        folder.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                composite.setSize(23, 43);
            }
        });


        item.setControl(composite);

        shell.setSize(300, 200);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

The `PaintListener` solution is **not a very elegant solution** but it works for my development environment.